Is it possible to fine-tune a pretrained word embedding model like vec2word?
I'm working on semantic matching in my search engine system. I saw that word embedding can be used for this task. However, my dataset is very limited and small, so I don't think that training a word embedding model such as word2vec from scratch will yield good results. As such, I decided to fine-tune a pre-trained model with my data.
However, I can't find a lot of information, such as articles or documentation, about fine-tuning. Some people even say that it's impossible to fine-tune a word embedding model.
This raises my question: is fine-tuning a pre-trained word embedding model possible and has anyone tried this before? Currently, I'm stuck and looking for more information. Should I try to train a word embedding model from scratch or are there other approaches?

As has been pointed out before, there is no "go-to" way for fine-tuning Word2Vec type models.
I would suggest training your own model from scratch, combining your data with other available data from a similar domain. Word2vec models are fairly quick to train and this would probably give you the best results. If you do not need static word-level embeddings, I would recommend considering contextualized embeddings, for example through the use of sentence-transformers or similar frameworks, which has a wide selection of already pre-trained models you can choose from. You can fine-tune these types of models on your specific data rather easily, and there are tons of resources online on how to do that.
For your use case, you can embed all the documents into dense vector representations using the abovementioned library, and then construct a searchable index over this semantic space. In order to match queries, all you have to do then is to embed the query using the same model and then retrieve the documents with the highest approximate inner product, often referred to as a MIPS search. An example library to take a look at would be faiss.

what about the mittens lirbary in python that is used for fine tunning word embedding ?

Sure, if you would like to use GloVe and not Word2Vec, that looks like a viable option. But if your goal is to create a semantic search engine, and your search queries are not individual words, you would need to aggregate all the query words regardless of the static embedding you choose, which probably means that you will be better of using contextualized embeddings, for example using BERT style models or some other embedding framework, which are easier to fine-tune on your custom data.

thank you for the information, based on your advice and more reading i realized that using contextualized embedding is more effective than using static embedding for individual words, so i decided to use bert, i am new to language models like bert and machine learning in general, so i am gonna read more about bert and see if i can fine tune it to my dataset and then use if for semantic similarity matching, but if you have any sources of information that can help me in my case i would appreciate, and thanks for the answer and the advice

It's possible (if you have the full word2vec model, which is more than just the word-vectors) to do additional training, Or, use existing vectors to initialize a model, that you then train further.
But, while this can be done, sometimes with beneficial results, there's no proven/robust recipe for the best way to do it.
Compared to training from scratch, when you're sure every word in the corpus had an equal chance to be co-trained into compatible positions alongside every other word, incremental fine-tuning requires a lot of extra choices about process & relative weighting, & careful attention to whether your specific choices are helping or hurting.
(In particular, if you have a large generic set of word-vectors, but then try to extend it with training over some new texts that don't cover all of its original vocabulary, the new words, and words that repeat, will continue to be pulled to new positions that are optimal only for the new texts, potentially losing their useful relative positioning with respect to other unmoved words not in the new texts. This might be survivable, if you don't do "too much" extra training! But it's a hard-to-quantify decay in the quality you want most – compatible word-vectors for all words of interest – directly trading off against learning your new words/texts.)
So rather than being as easy "shortcut" to an expanded set of word-vectors, as one might hope, fine-tuning can require extra complications & work.
My impression is that two alternate approaches are better:

Extend your corpus with other texts that should have compatible word-senses - perhaps making your triing corpus arbitrarily larger than your starting data, but ensuring that all words – from your starting texts, and the expanded corpus – get co-trained word-vectors covering all words of interest.

Train on your smaller corpus, then as a separate step learn a projection that moves your words into the coordinate space of a larger model whose full range of words you think good enough as a basis, using the 'anchoring points' of shared words.


(This 2nd technique is briefly mentioned in the Google "skip-thoughts" paper (section 2.2 "vocabulary expansion"), and also used in this paper on learning/improving interlanguage translations between word-vector sets. There's a class inside the Gensim python project called TranslationMatrix that can learn such mappings, and also another project on PyPI called transvec that may work for such purposes.)
